# Does deleting row from mysql innodb table frees up the space?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.7 . Some of my tables contains 14-15 GBs of audit data. I want to keep only last year data and want to move rest of the rows into a archive table.
So, I am creating a table with `engine="archive"`, and will insert all rows except last year into that table.

Then, I will delete these rows from the main table. Will it free up the spaces of my main table after performing the delete? Is it the correct archiving approach or there is other best approach available?

Comment: No, disk space is not freed up during rows deletion.

Comment: if I run optimize table, it will freed up, right?

Comment: Depends on a lot of facts. Assuming the engine is InnoDB and file_per_table is set this is true.